# Upgrade Eclipse java compiler

Tags: java, eclipse

I started using Ant, that ships with Eclipse. It annoys me, that I get hundreds of warnings in the lines of:

> [javac] warning:
>   java\io\BufferedInputStream.class(java\io:BufferedInputStream.class):
>   major version 51 is newer than 50, the
>   highest major version supported by
>   this compiler.
>       [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.

How do I upgrade compiler?

Comment: What version of Eclipse and the JDK?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

download and install newer version of JDK.

`Windows - > Preference - > Java - > Installed JRE` set newer version here

Comment: Already done tried that, along with changing the appropriate paths, yet I still get the warning

Comment: if you still got that warning, check your run configuration of your ant file, instead of `Run As -> Ant Build` try the `Run As -> Ant Build...`-option (have a close look at the three little dots at the end). Then check the tab JRE and select the proper (the updated) jre

Answer (score 11):

Major version 51 is Java 7 - looks like you're developing against a preview Java 7 API library but compiling with a Java 6 javac. Either make sure ant uses the Java 7 compiler, or use a Java 6 API library to compile against.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks, I figured it out.

For those whom it may concern, to make sure Ant uses the Java 7 compiler:

```
Preferences -> Ant -> Runtime -> Classpath -> Global Entries
```

Click `Add External Jars` and put your `tools.jar` here.

It will look something like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\lib`

Comment: This too didn't work for me, my ant path is already pointed to the highest version..still get the warning

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1. Download last JDK and install it.
2. Go to `C:/Program files/Java` and delete the *previous* JDK.
3. Update your `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` Environment Variables with the new JDK.
4. Open Eclipse and in Windows > Preference > Java > Installed JRE, set newer version here

If there is a broken link with a jar in previous JDK, Eclipse will notify you. I solved in this way the problem with `tools.jar` ant reference, but it is a general way to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since my development environment should be based on Java 6 the only thing that helped for this problem was removing Java 7 at all

Answer (score 0):

I solved my warning with answer from Bao.
I had JDK1.6 installed before.
Then installed JDK1.7 and ant was stil using JKD1.6 for compiling.

What I have changed is also set the JDK for the project:
right click on project > properties > Java Build Path

If you have JDK1.6 here, try to change it to JDK1.7.

Answer (score 0):

One additional thing you probably also need to do is to go under the JRE tab of the Edit Configuration window and select the JRE version.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, Unfortunately this is not an answer. Please add such tips as a comment in future.