# Downgrade Eclipse ant to compile while using older JDK libraries (Java 1.7 -> 1.6)

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, java-6, java-7

I have the opposite problem as [Upgrade Eclipse java compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267760/upgrade-eclipse-java-compiler): I'm using Eclipse 3.7.1 that *can* support JDK 1.7, but right now I am developing for JDK 1.6... which has been working fine, but suddenly I'm getting tons of errors like this when I do an ant build (see below).

I want to use JDK 1.6; where do I set that? Eclipse is set properly (Java Build Path for each project points to JRE System Library [jdk1.6.0_16]), but ant seems to be disregarding it.

```
[javac] warning: java\nio\ByteBuffer.class(java\nio:ByteBuffer.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\lang\Object.class(java\lang:Object.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\util\Collections.class(java\util:Collections.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
[javac] warning: java\util\EnumMap.class(java\util:EnumMap.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
[javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
```

---

update: More clues -- this is the first time I've built this particular project in a separate Eclipse workspace that imports the project from a previous workspace. I switched back to the old workspace and built the same project and it builds fine.

The difference seems to be that ant runs in a 1.7 JRE in my new workspace, but ant runs in a 1.6 JRE in my old workspace. What gives? Where do I set this? I can't seem to figure out which setting is different.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

found it:

In the Ant tab in Eclipse, if you right-click on your build, and click Run As -> Ant Build..., then it will pop up an "Edit Configuration" dialog box, and you can select which JRE you want to use for Ant.

I don't know where this setting is stored, but it appears to be stored in the workspace rather than with the project settings.

Comment: Setting can be found in `Run - External Tools - External Tools Configurations` under the JRE-Tab for the selected Ant-Build config.

Comment: Worked for me too. Note - Sometimes eclipse needs to be restarted after this change is done.